# Xdebug running on remote host: cannot connect back to client -> timeout

Tags: php, docker, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

Since two days I try to get my Xdebug configuration running without success what drives me crazy!

#### My setup

Client: Macbook Pro with PhpStorm

Xdebug is running on a remote server ( Ubuntu 18.04 ) in a Docker ( latest stable version ) container behind the jwilder/nginx proxy.

Xdebug runs on PHP 7.3.9, Xdebug version is 2.7.2

Xdebug Settings:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remode_mode=req
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

The `xdebug.remote_host` is `docker.host.internal` because I copied my config file from my local xdebug.ini. On Mac you use this value. In this case `xdebug.remote_host` will be ignored because `xdebug.remote_connect_back` is on.

This is the phpinfo page (too big to display an actual image here).

[phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9r5g.jpg)

This is the output in my xdebug log file

```
[17] Log opened at 2019-09-07 07:40:29
[17] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[17] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[17] I: Remote address found, connecting to 178.203.235.46:10000.
[17] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
[17] Log closed at 2019-09-07 07:40:29
```

This is my remote Xdebug validation in PhpStorm:

[image: Xdebug validation in PhpStorm]

Its seems like everything should run: PhpStorm is setup correctly ( listening on port 10000 ) - but its not!!!

What have i tried: almost everything. I used older Xdebug versions, other PHP versions... nothing. Always the timeout when Xdebug wants to connect to my client.

Also I disabled `xdebug.remote_connect_back` and used the `HTTP_X_REAL_IP` as xdebug.remote_host --> timeout.

Then I thought maybe its the nginx proxy. So I tried it without it -> same error: timeout.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "remote server"? is it just to describe Docker container ... or is it actually running on another computer elsewhere (not where IDE is running)? 2) Ensure that PhpStorm is the one that listens on TCP 10000 port (`sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` or alike, e.g. `netstat` perhaps) 3) Make sure it's not a firewall issue.

Comment: remote server is a computer somewhere else

Comment: Well ... make sure then that the Xdebug connection can make all way out of the remote server and your local computer/router allows incoming connections on Xdebug port. `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal` is not going to work ... as in this case it simply tries to connect to Docker's host OS and that's it (unless, you have some SSH tunnel/forwarding that will pass the connection further back to your local computer).

Comment: So SSH to remote server (not docker container) and try to connect back to IDE from there (e.g. using telnet). If it works -- dig deeper/next step; if not -  fix it. Just in case: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication -- to see how Xdebug works.

Comment: i cannot telnet from the remote server to my client. i switched of my mac firewall and the firewall in my router.   root@vmd43009:~# telnet 178.203.233.182
Trying 178.203.233.182...  .any ideas how to fix this ? im absoloutley not into network / firewall stugg :-(

Comment: Use SSH tunnels then (from your Mac to remote server). If all done correctly then xdebug connection that comes from the Docker container will reach host OS and will connect to SSH port that will forward it back to your computer. It's still a bit complicated (as it's SSH + Docker) -- see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: okay ssh tunnel is setup and i can telnet from my remote machine to my macbook. i have set xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 now but it does not work...but thats clear because 127.0.0.1 in xdebug config is my docker container and not the remote host. do you know how to set this up? i tried to expose port 10000 in my docker-compose file which did not work-

Comment: 1) You do not need to expose anything: if you expose Docker will occupy that port for itself (to accept incoming connections) .. while asp per Xdebug link I gave before it's Xdebug that connects to IDE (so it's an outgoing connection). 2) `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1` this is simply wrong as Xdebug will be trying to connect to a port in the same container .. which is wrong. It has to be your host machine IP, so `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal` should be OK.

Comment: The idea is: Xdebug connection must get out of the container to the host OS, where it should connect to an already opened SSH port that will forward connection  to your local dev machine.

Comment: thanky for your help! still not working though. with host.docker.internal i get this error: [16] Log opened at 2019-09-09 18:55:34
[16] I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:10000.
[16] W: Creating socket for 'host.docker.internal:10000', getaddrinfo: Invalid argument.
[16] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[16] Log closed at 2019-09-09 18:55:34... after that i tried to set xdebug.remote_host to the remote host ip address and then i get following error: Poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29). 4th day now to fix this :-(

Comment: Maybe Xdebug connection cannot get out of container ... (docker/host OS restriction or firewall?) Can you somehow SSH into container and try telnet from there? Cannot suggest anything better than that...

Comment: At the same time a bit silly question: that reversed SSH tunnel -- does it active at that time ... and does it work at all (I mean: can you connect to IDE on Xdebug port? when it's listening for connections (connection should succeed) and when it's not (connection should fail).

Comment: ssh tunnel is working fine from client to remote host! at least! when i ssh into docker container nothing works. i actually have no idea which ip address i should try? could ne the jwilder/ngingx proxy be a problem?  docker-container ip address is 172.27.0.3 which is in the same network as the nginx proxy. gateway is 172.19.0.1

Comment: These answers helped me a lot. In case it may help someone else, I run Ubuntu Server 18.04 in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host, with a bridged connection. I use VSCode and Chrome (with xdebug helper). In my case I had to take these steps: (in `php.ini`) `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0`, `xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1`, no `xdebug.idekey`, I add to change the port to 9002 because of conflicts. I added a rule to ufw to enable port 9002 with `sudo ufw allow 9002`, restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this post a couple of years ago which might be helpful: https://medium.com/@pavlakis/setting-up-xdebug-with-docker-and-php-7-2-f5a6553cb956

In case the proxy you're using is giving you a different IP, try the following: https://github.com/phpminds/website/blob/master/docker.sh